# how to use object inside another objects function

Tags: jquery, object

I have an object 'params' and another object 'options' whith function assigned to its parameter. And I want to use 'params' element inside 'options' function. How can I do that?

```
 var params = {
     'errorId': 'dd.error',
 }  $(function() {
var options = {
    'success': function() { alert(params['errorId']; }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `var` keyword from `params` to make it available later/globally:

```
 params = {
     'errorId': 'dd.error',
 }  $(function() {
var options = {
    'success': function() { alert(params['errorId']; }

});
```

Comment: @Ahmed You should do `var params;` at the highest level that you want to be scoped to. If you don't, the variable will be global, which is bad practice and could cause you problems elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Hm. It looks like you're missing a curly brace after options. What doesn't work? Do you get a syntax error? The code there, other than the missing curly, looks like it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

There's some errors in your posted code.

It should look more like this: [Live example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/tc6ME/)

```
var params = {
    'errorId': 'dd.error',
};

$(function() {
    var options = {
        'success': function() {
            alert(params['errorId']); // <--- added missing ')'
        }
    }; // <-- added missing '}' to options var

    options.success(); // <--- added by me to execute function
});
```